# Finding starting and ending column name

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2003

Suppose I have data as below in excel.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  A  +  B  +  C  +  D  +  E  +  F  +  G  +  H  +  I  +  J  +  K  +  L  +  M  +  N  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     +  1  +  2  +  3  +  4  +  4  +  1  +  1  +  2  +  3  +  7  +  3  +  4  +  1  +
+     +  1  +  2  +  3  +  3  +  4  +  2  +  1  +  2  +  3  +  7  +  3  +  4  +  1  +
+     +  0  +  1  +  2  +  3  +  6  +  6  +  3  +  2  +  3  +  7  +  3  +  4  +  1  +
+     +  0  +  0  +  0  +  0  +  0  +  0  +  0  +  0  +  0  +  0  +  0  +  0  +  0  +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I wanted to find is the incorrect row i.e. all column should not have 0. To get this I am using below formulae in Cell N.

**`=if(SUM(B1:M1)>0,1,0)`**

***NOTE : All cell will have non-negative numbers only.***

In above example I have 4th row as incorrect row and hence I have value as 0.

What I wanted is, instead of writing manually `B1:M1`, is there any way in excel that will display the starting and ending cell/column name.

In above example

```
Starting cell/column will be B
Ending cell/column will be   M
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve? You already have the formula. Simply put it in N1 and drag it down?

Comment: @SiddharthRout : I am doing the same, however for every sheet I need to ***EDIT*** the formulae. So I wanted to find the way to find the first and last column so that I don't need to EDIT my formulae...

Comment: Do you mean to say that in every sheet, it is not necessary that the data will start at Col B and end in Col M? If yes then you might have to opt in for a VBA solution.

Comment: @SiddharthRout : You are right, but I don't want to use VBA. I am looking some solution within Excel itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for [Named Range](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s7p6.html) built-in feature of Excel.

Create a named range on `B:M` and use it in your formulas. Named ranges are a way to write consistent identical formulas across spreadsheets hitting heterogeneous ranges

Comment: NO, this is not what I was looking for.

Comment: If you think your solution is what I am looking for then could you provide solution using above example?

Comment: If it s not what you are looking for, then there is no other way but named ranges to give a name to a range, so the answer to your question will be that is is not possible to do it another way.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it without vba (but it makes me shudder at the abuse I'm putting excel through :)

I have used row 5 for these calculations - alter the 5 to your needs

Cell 1 - beginning column - enter as an *array* formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) `=MATCH(TRUE,5:5>0,0)` (excel will put `{}` around it if entered correctly
Cell 2 - number of columns - `=COUNTA(5:5)`
Final Cell - your check - `=if(SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5,Cell_1)&":"&ADDRESS(5,Cell_1+Cell_2)))>0,1,0)`